# Permutation restricted to subset, reorder the range

Tags: permutations

Consider the set of numbers $N = \{ 1, \dots, n \}$ and let $S \subseteq N$ be a subset.

Now let $\pi : N \rightarrow N$ be bijective, so $\pi$ is a permutation of the numbers from $1$ to $n$.

Then $\pi(S) \subset N$ is another subset, and generally the permutation will not list the elements of $S$ in the correct order. What is the sign of the permutation over $\pi(S)$ that orders them back?

Comment: Generally the restriction of $\pi$ to $S$ will not be a permutation of $S$, so it is unclear what "list the elements of $S$ in the correct order" refers to.

Comment: Read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

If $S=\{m_1,m_2,\dots,m_k\}\subseteq N$, then we can write
$$\pi(S) = \{\pi(m_1),\pi(m_2),\dots,\pi(m_k)\}.$$